# Find the probability for ...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, permutations, problem-solving

> Suppose we uniformly and randomly select permutations from the 20!
>   Permutations of 1, 2, 3,..., 20.  What is the probability that 2
>   appears at an earlier position than any other even number in the
>   selected permutation?

A. 0.5 
B. 0.1
C. 9! / 20!
D. None

**According to the work book** the answer is **(D)**

However **am getting the answer as 0.1**

**Here goes the explanation.**

The first even number is 2. 
Selection of these numbers is analogies to arranging them in 20 blanks.

- Suppose 2 is filled in the first blank. then the remaining 19 elements can be arranged in 19! Ways.
- Suppose 2 goes into the second blank. The 1st blank can be occupied by an odd number in 10P1 ways and the 2nd blank can be filled with 2 in 1 way while the remaining 18 blanks can be filled in 18! Ways 
  Hence (10P1)(1)(18!) ways
- Suppose 2 goes into the third blank. The 1st two blanks can be occupied by two odd number in 10P2 ways and the 3nd blank can be filled with 2 in 1 way while the remaining 18 blanks can be filled in 17! Ways 
  Hence (10P2)(1)(17!) ways

Generalizing the above three steps.

> For i = 0 to 10
>
> Summation of
>
> (  *<sup>10</sup>P<sub>i</sub> )(1)(19 - i )!*

Evaluating the above summation in the calc, I got 1/10 = **0.1**

Let me know if I missed anything in the calculation.

Comment: Each of the 10 even numbers has an equal chance of being the first one, so , 0.1 seems right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you, and think there is a much easier explanation.  As you fill in the list, if you pick an odd number it doesn't matter.  The only question is whether the first even you pick is $2$ or something else.  There are $10$ evens to pick, so the chance the first one is $2$ is $1/10$